# Drawing a tree-like graph - how to organize the storage array?

Tags: java, graph, tree, pseudocode, graph-algorithm

The question is generally language-independent (although if that matters, I am using Java/Processing). I need to draw a tree-like graph using some database output. The rules are are simple:

Graph has only one Root.
Each Node can have several children, but only one parent.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to serve data to the drawing function. The database I am getting data from (it's Rails/MySQL) has following structure (I am using pseudocode to avoid unnecessary self-referential has_many :through details) :

```
Graph
 has_many :nodes

Node
 has_many :siblings
 has_one :parent
 has_many :children
```

Question is - how should I organize the array that I put the Nodes information into and how to loop through that array? A pseudo-code for the algo would be amazing.

If you find that some info is missing for the answer to happen, let me know, I will be happy to expand the question / add data.

P.S. I am not really looking for suggestions on some frameworks/services that can draw graphs for me, I actually need to do that using my current tools.

Thanks!

EDIT :

That's how I am drawing graph now...  It takes word one by one from an array like ['0root', '2child', 2child2', '4child_child'] and reconstructs the tree assuming that if (int) prefix of next element of array is larger by 2 it's a child and if it's smaller by 2, it's  one level up (sibling of a parent). The position relative to siblings is calculated from total number of elements with the same prefix in the array.. I wonder if there is a more elegant way to do that..?

Graph() {
        wordList = new ArrayList();
        nodeList = new ArrayList();
        sibList = new ArrayList();
      }

```
  Integer sibNumber(int idx<char>) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> sibCount = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (Integer sibling: sibList) {
      Integer count = sibCount.get(sibling);
      sibCount.put(sibling, (count==null) ? 1 : count+1);
    }
    Integer result = sibCount.get(idx);
    return result;
  }


  void update(String wrd) {
    wordList.add(wrd);

    String word = wrd;
    String[][] m = matchAll(wrd, "(\\d*)");
    int index = (int) m[0][0];
    char number = (char) index;
    sibList.add(index);
//    println(wrd);
    word = word.replaceAll(number,"");
    Integer siblingsNum = sibNumber(index);
    if (sibList.size()>=2) {
      lastIndex = sibList.get(sibList.size()-2);
      int indexDiff = index-lastIndex;
      if (indexDiff != 0) {
        for (int i=sibList.size()-1; i>0; i--) {
          if (index-sibList.get(i) == 2) {
            parNode = nodeList.get(i);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (index == 2) {
      parNode = nodeList.get(0);
    }

    node = new Node(word, index, siblingsNum, parNode);
    nodeList.add(node);

  }

  void clean() {
    nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();
    sibList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  }


  void display() {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++) {
      nd =  nodeList.get(i);

      if (nd.parent != null) {

        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        VerletSpring2D spring=new VerletSpring2D(nd.origin,nd.parent.origin,80,0.01);
        physics.addParticle(nd.origin);
        physics.addSpring(spring);
        line(nd.origin.x+nd.w/2, nd.origin.y, nd.parent.origin.x+nd.w/2, nd.parent.origin.y+nd.parent.h);
      }
      nd.display();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using an array, Why can't you have a class called "Node" which can suit the purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use an array? The natural solution to this problem is to implement a 'Node' class, which has references to child Nodes. This lends itself to a recursive algorithm which will allow you to (for example) find a specific Node.
All you then need to start with is a reference to the root Node.

```
public class Node {
  private Node parent;
  private List<Node> children;

  public Node findNode(String nodeName) {
    // Is it this node?
    // Iterate through all child nodes, calling findNode on each
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to pass data from Rails model to actual graph_draw() function, which is written in Java/Processing so I have to somehow inform graph_draw() about what kind of node it is receiving (does it have children? does it have siblings?).. I guess I have trouble figuring which parameters I should pass along with actual Node.content..

Comment: What parameters is graph_draw() expecting? Is this a third party library you are using? Is there any documentation for the API?

Comment: graph_draw() is just a function that I have in Processing, it can take any parameter.. I will update the question with more info about that function: